# How can I push a component into an array then render it?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have a "god Ticker" that is sort of like a timer that starts at 0 and keeps going. I want to push a component to an array at random times as the god Ticker progresses. I tried to render the array in real time in return(), but whenever I push a component into the array, nothing appears.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, the god Ticker state is being updated every millisecond, so render function is being called every millisecond

```
render() {
  if (this.state.godTicker == this.obsInterval) {
    this.myObstaclesPlz.push(
      <Obstacle
        obsImage={this.state.myCacti[Math.round(Math.random() * 3.5)]}
        godTicker={this.state.godTicker}
      />
    );
    this.obsInterval = this.state.godTicker + Math.round(Math.random() * 110 + 40);
  }

  return <View style={styles.container}>{this.myObstaclesPlz}</View>;
}
```

Comment: nothing will happen, re-render only happens if either state or props are changed. You are just pushing into a class variable, so its ignored by react. Also never do any operation like push or setstate in the render method.

Comment: also learn how to manipulate data immutably

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier I know I shouldnt put setState in render, but why not push?

Comment: You should do what you're doing in `componentDidMount` and include `myObstaclesPlz ` as a state object (`this.state.myObstaclesPlz`) that you modify in `componentDidMount` with setState and then use in your `render` method (like you're doing in the return).